# Type Ahead property for contact list in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, type-ahead

I want to develop one application in blackberry.In that application i want to create functinality like in contact list i.e if there are many contacts in contact list & if i enter "Da"then it should return me the results like "Dany","Daniel",etc.(i.e. Type ahead property )so how should i go for it.the input(i.e. contact list) i am using to search in is Vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [AutoCompleteField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/AutoCompleteField.html)?  It should do what you want.

---

You can access the filtered set by keeping a reference to the BasicFilteredList, or by calling getFilteredList() on the AutoCompleteField.  Then make use of the [ReadableList](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/) interface methods to access the filtered output.

Comment: AutoCompleteField requires BasicFilteredList as a collection while i want to use Vector as my collection.

Comment: if I enter any word in autocompletefield then it will return results according to my input.now i want to propagate to new screen according to selected result by me so how should it be possible?